# c# Unable to insert newline in string

Tags: c#, html

I am having issue inserting newline in the text message below. At the moment I am using Environment.NewLine but that doesnt seem to work.
This is how it is showing.

[image]

Code

```
  error =
                            @"You cannot split a sale@
                              <ul>
                                <li>With yourself.</li>            
                                <li>A representative that has not completed their IBA and not been approved by compliance.</li>
                                <li>A terminated representative.</li>
                                </ul>".Replace("@", Environment.NewLine)
```

I basically want to show it like this

```
You cannot split a sale

•   With yourself.            
•   A representative that has not completed their IBA and not been approved by compliance.
•   A terminated representative.
```

***EDIT***

html

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
        <div *ngIf="infoMessage" class="notification warning">
          <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'info-circle']"></fa-icon>
          <span [innerHTML]="infoMessage"></span>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.notification {
  background: #d3d3d3;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 7.5px 10px;
  width: 100%;

  span {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  }
}
.notification.success { background: $notification-success; color: $white; }
.notification.warning { background: $notification-warning; color: $white; }
.notification.error   { background: $pink; color: $white; }
```

Comment: Did you try to <br/> 
</ul>".Replace("@", "<br/> ")

Comment: HTML ignores newlines. You need to use `<div>`, or `<br/>`. The best option would be to put the description in its own div and don't replace anything, ie `<div>You cannot split a sale</div>`

Comment: BTW `<ul>` itself always appears in a new line. The image you posted has nothing to do with newlines. The style applied to the HTML page forced the `ul` to appear in a separate *column*. You'll have to find the CSS styles applied to `ul` in your HTML page

Comment: You could try wrapping the entire block in a `<div>`, perhaps that will prevent `ul` from appearing in a separate column. In any case, without the CSS people can only guess

Comment: what is the css definition of : notification warning ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change

```
.Replace("@", Environment.NewLine)
```

by

```
.Replace("@", "<br />")
```

`Environement.NewLine` is `\r\n`

This is pointless in HTML code.
`<br />` is the equivalent in HTML code.

Why using `<br />` instead of `\r\n`, it because your error string seems to be interpreted when you are displaying it, looks like on a website. `\r\n` would have been fin in desktop application.

Edit: Or you can update your initial code by the following one.

```
 error =
                            @"You cannot split a sale
<p>
                              <ul>
                                <li>With yourself.</li>            
                                <li>A representative that has not completed their IBA and not been approved by compliance.</li>
                                <li>A terminated representative.</li>
                                </ul></p>"
```

*Code Snippet*

```html
You cannot split a sale
<p>
  <ul>
    <li>With yourself.</li>
    <li>A representative that has not completed their IBA and not been approved by compliance.</li>
    <li>A terminated representative.</li>
  </ul>
</p>

<h4> Same With BR</h4>
  You cannot split a sale
  <br />

  <ul>
    <li>With yourself.</li>
    <li>A representative that has not completed their IBA and not been approved by compliance.</li>
    <li>A terminated representative.</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: is it a website? any cache?

Comment: @Tom it works - that's how HTML works. Newlines are ignored. If you want to move to a different line, you need to use `<br/>` or enclose the section you want to appear separately in a `<div>` or `<p>`, or any of the other block elements

Comment: @Tom since newlines are *ignored*, what you posted would never appear in plain HTML - btw `<ul>` itself *already* appears in a separate line. Some style was applied to your HTML that makes the `<ul>` element appear in a different *column*

Comment: I have updated the post with the html the way i am displaying

Comment: Update the post with css

Comment: @Tom: Your responses (and question edit) are not in response to what is being said. The asked question has been answered - it appears your situation has a lot of custom alterations that are changing the default style rules as defined in HTML which answerers cannot reasonably account for. This would require trawling through all your CSS which is frankly out of scope for a question. "It doesn't work" isn't constructive feedback, what exactly do you expect we can do in response to that?

Comment: I marking the answer as worked . Had to tweak in my styles thought. I had to change from inline-flex to inline